# Can't run Flutter Project `Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found`

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I found this issue while running my Flutter project on Android Studio. Please kindly guide me to resolve this issue. I can't run my project.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N985F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Previously I tried to do 1). Flutter Clean, 2). Flutter Pub Get.

> I know this issue relating to the gradle. I tried to delete the .gradle folder but here is the things. I CAN'T FOUND THAT FOLDER in my project, is not exist.